# Is there a benefit to having NAS with ECC memory and ZFS filesystem when I work on systems with neither?

Tags: backup, nas, zfs, ecc

Recently I've read some alarming stats on corruption rates in systems with non-ECC RAM and typical filesystems. From what I can Google, having a system with ECC RAM running ZFS is probably the best way to prevent corruption. Most of that information has been in the context of NAS discussions.

I can see how having such a system would be useful for archiving files, assuming they aren't already corrupt on the source machine and are transferred over the network perfectly.

What I haven't been able to Google is this: what is the point of having maximally reliable NAS hosting files (or as backup) when I'm working with the files on less reliable computers? I'm also not able to find good information on error correction in Samba (whatever the latest version is in a ZFS-capable OS like FreeNAS or OpenIndiana) - if it's at all error-prone, then almost everything else is pointless (unless I personally hash everything and verify all transfers).

Do I need to (figuratively) throw away my current systems and replace them with (mini) server-grade hardware if I don't want to worry about bit rot and etc.? And if I go that route, could I reasonably expect to have resources for anything beyond running ZFS? Without spending thousands of dollars?

My use case:

I'm concerned with more than just playback (e.g. of movies and other media). I frequently do programming work on my home computers. For example, I have an ever-increasing number of SQLite database files for various projects. Having one of those become corrupt could be a problem. I also have many gigabytes of family and vacation photos that I not only want to archive but also organize, tag, etc. So although I'm not running a bank, I have things that would be difficult to replace and I hate to think of them being "silently corrupted".

Comment: I've recently been exploring a lot of the same issues you bring up here. I'm interested to know if you have come to any conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The connection:**

I attempted to read the documentation on the Samba website, but was unable to determine whether Samba has error-correction. I had to assume the worst case - that Samba relies on the underlying network to be error free. If that underlying network is TCP/IP, it seems the only protection is a weak checksum.

I wound up going with iSCSI because it supports optional header and data digests which use the CRC32C algorithm. That's over and above the TCP/IP checking.

**Is there any benefit?**

For me the answer is "Yes, in at least one scenario." I can backup files to a server-grade ZFS machine using a program I trust. Then I can periodically check whether *supposedly* unmodified files on the original machine are *actually* unmodified. If there's a discrepancy, I can restore the backup from the server.

The only weak point is when files are being intentionally modified on the unreliable consumer-grade machine. Because corruption during those short periods of time is so unlikely, I find that acceptable. If I happen to discover corruption has occurred during modification I will have incremental backups to fall back on.

**Replacing my computer with a server powerful enough to run ZFS and have the resources left over to be my primary computer?**

Maybe, but it would be extremely expensive. I'm satisfied with the scenario described above, so I won't be attempting this.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. I'm curious how you are achieving this part: "I can periodically check whether supposedly unmodified files on the original machine are actually unmodified." That seems like it might be difficult to implement and result in a lot of false positives (i.e. I assume that when a user intentionally modifies a file, it would be flagged). Thanks.

Comment: @DominicP - How to determine intent is probably beyond the scope of the question. In brief: Use a database to track file hash and modification time, and assume that a cosmic ray (or whatever) changing both is unlikely.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

**ZFS is quite picky about what hardware it runs on.**

Not in the sense that you have to have exactly the right chipset, graphics card, disk firmware version and so on, but in the sense of capabilities provided by the hardware. Remember, ZFS was designed as a high-end server solution, and certain assumptions it makes reflects that.

A major portion of what makes ZFS so great for storing data that you care about is that you can set it up in ways that can both detect *and correct* errors in storage. This can be trivial errors like a single bit flip somewhere, or catastrophic errors like several disks crashing at once. As long as you stay above your storage layout's redundancy threshold (for example, no more than two disks simultaneously experiencing problems in a raidz2 vdev) ZFS can correct any error using redundant data. Further errors, depending on where and how they occur, can lead to a (semi-) graceful system panic, or a simple I/O error.

If you do it right, you will also set up your system to scrub the ZFS pool(s) at regular intervals. This will catch degredation before it becomes a problem, and will notify you to it so you can consider replacing the storage devices that are having trouble holding on to your data before this becomes a problem.

However, that greatness *depends on the fact that RAM can be trusted.* All this validation, correction, rewriting and so on happens primarily in RAM. On high-end servers, you don't find anything but ECC RAM.

**ZFS protects (and handles) pool metadata, file system metadata and user data the same way.** There is no real difference here.

If your workstation system experiences a RAM bit flip, then when you write the bit-flipped data out to ZFS, the bit-flipped data will be the basis for what ZFS eventually writes out to disk. This is obviously bad, because it means your file will be corrupted. However, the bit-flipped data will be *correct as far as ZFS is concerned*. This is actually *good*, because it means that all the normal ZFS recovery methods will work. Yes, the most recent copy of the file in question will be corrupt, but *it would be corrupt anyway,* no matter what file system you were using. *You can leverage ZFS's snapshots* to at least be able to go back in time to an uncorrupted copy. Set up something like [zfs-auto-snap](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs-auto-snapshot) to snapshot your file systems at regular, close intervals, keep a coarser history going backwards, and forget about it until you need them. (For example, keep ten snapshots spaced ten minutes apart; 50 snapshots one hour apart; 30 snapshots six hours apart; and so on.) Snapshots are practically free in ZFS; if you use ZFS, *use snapshots* as well.

If your storage server which runs ZFS experiences bad RAM, whether a bit flip or a stuck (one or more) bits, and you have ECC RAM in the storage server, this will be detected, and the event will be logged or the system will be halted (if the error cannot be corrected for). Either way, the integrity of the data that is stored on the server is preserved. If your ZFS storage server has non-ECC RAM, **then an error can propagate throughout all your data and metadata** as ZFS attempts to "correct" the errors that really are only figments of the computer's imagination. As a worst case scenario, [which actually happens to people](http://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/ecc-vs-non-ecc-ram-and-zfs.15449/), your entire pool will be wrecked because of this and all your data will be gone. Storage-level/vdev-level redundancy doesn't help here, either. With most other file systems (without the auto-correcting behavior) only the one place which was directly affected by the bit flip will be corrupted, and if this happens to file system metadata is likely to be easily fixed by traditional file system checkers and recovery tools. ZFS does not have this escape hatch; *there is no fsck.zfs.* (There is *zpool scrub*, but that doesn't work if the pool is broken beyond repair.)

> What I haven't been able to Google is this: what is the point of having maximally reliable NAS hosting files (or as backup) when I'm working with the files on less reliable computers?

**It means you have a trusted data repository.** You know that once data has made it to your NAS, it's safe from corruption. Any corruption will either be repaired automatically, or you will be informed about the problem (in the case of ZFS, via an I/O error). The data might still be corrupted while it's being worked on using less reliable systems, but you will have some place to go for a known non-corrupted copy. This is an advantage even if only the NAS system has ECC RAM, ZFS and high-quality storage monitoring and alerts set up.

You can then, if desired, add (particularly) ECC RAM to your other system(s) as your budget permits, to plug the last hole.

> Do I need to (figuratively) throw away my current systems and replace them with (mini) server-grade hardware if I don't want to worry about bit rot and etc.? And if I go that route, could I reasonably expect to have resources for anything beyond running ZFS? Without spending thousands of dollars?

First, you don't really need server grade hardware. **What you need is primarily ECC RAM (and a CPU and memory controller/chipset that supports ECC RAM),** reasonably reliable permanent storage, and ideally a case that makes it easy to add and remove disks while the system is running. This doesn't have to be very expensive, and certainly does not need to cost "thousands of dollars".

Second, ZFS likes RAM, but mainly for caching. With most workloads, 8-16 GB of RAM should be quite enough, and 24-32 GB (easily attainable even with "consumer" motherboards) is still reasonably priced even when buying high-quality brand-name ECC RAM. ZFS isn't terribly CPU hungry; you can make it need lots of CPU (like with [ZoL](http://zfsonlinux.org/), by setting up sha256, gzip-9 compression and possibly deduplication in combination), but you don't have to. My own system runs ZFS, isn't terribly high-powered (FX-6100 CPU clocked down), I use sha256 everywhere, and even in purely sequential I/O the disks are the limiting factor: once it gets past the initial small-random-reads portion of the scrub, I get about the same throughput on scrubs as I do on a raw `dd` from the underlying storage device, with CPU to spare.

Answer (score 1):

> What I haven't been able to Google is this: what is the point of having maximally
>   reliable NAS hosting files (or as backup) when I'm working with the files on less
>   reliable computers?

The chance of something going wrong it cumulative.

In other words (and with fake numbers):
 If there is a 10% chance things go wrong on the NAS, and
 If there is a 10% chance things go wrong on the other device,
 Then you have a 20% chance of failure when reading something from the NAS and playing it on the other device.

> I'm also not able to find good information on error correction in Samba

Which samba version. The protocols changed quite a bit between the three versions.

> if it's at all error-prone, then almost everything else is pointless (unless
>   I personally hash everything and verify all transfers).

There is always a risk of errors. These simply do occur. And they do get detected and corrected (e.g. via checksums).  This is not always true when using RAM, which is something you can improve by using parity and/or ECC. However these problems are relative unlikely and you need to find a balance between gold plated (and expensive) design and "good enough".

This balance will be quite different for some of us (e.g. banks needs things perfectly). They probably do not warrant using ECC on personal systems meant to play movies.